# SPARQL CONSTRUCT: restrict scope of BIND variable?

Tags: sparql

I am using Jena ARQ with this query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sc: <http://iiif.io/api/presentation/2#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX as: <http://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams#>
CONSTRUCT {?collectionIRI rdf:type sc:Collection .
?collectionIRI as:items ?manifest .
?manifest rdf:type sc:Manifest} 
WHERE {GRAPH ?g {?manifest rdf:type sc:Manifest .
BIND (URI(STR(CONCAT("https://api.repository.org/orgs/example.domain.org/collections/" , STRUUID()))) AS ?collectionIRI) .
FILTER(regex(str(?manifest),"example.domain.org"))  
}}
```

The intention is to create a **single** `?collectionIRI` by BINDing `STRUUID()` to a domain name (e.g. "example.domain.org" - a query parameter).

With this query every `?manifest` in the result set is bound to a different `?collectionIRI` and the result looks like this:

```
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "https://api.repository.org/orgs/example.domain.org/collections/0342aaf2-b772-48ea-be90-298a555ef5ab",
      "@type": "sc:Collection",
      "items": "http://example.domain.org/unescoCzechReformation/AIPDIG-NKCR__X_C_23______3CKR674-cs/"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.repository.org/orgs/example.domain.org/collections/04782c88-81cf-4d7b-8ac6-f15d83f094a5",
      "@type": "sc:Collection",
      "items": "http://example.domain.org/unescoCzechReformation/AIPDIG-NKCR__VIII_G_26___38E5KUD-cs/"
    }
  ]
}
```

instead of the desired result:

```
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "https://api.repository.org/orgs/example.domain.org/collections/0342aaf2-b772-48ea-be90-298a555ef5ab",
      "@type": "sc:Collection",
      "items": [
        "http://example.domain.org/unescoCzechReformation/AIPDIG-NKCR__VIII_B_6____30XYOX6-cs/",
        "http://example.domain.org/unescoCzechReformation/AIPDIG-NKCR__I_E_45______2KDU8A5-cs/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to restrict BIND scope with CONSTRUCT?

Comment: Either curly braces around the BIND statement could work. Otherwise, just put it into a sub-SELECT query.

Comment: Thanks.  The braces around the BIND statement work.